# Flot Javascript - drawing a 24 hour bar chart with values every hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I want to create using Flot Charts a 24 hour bar graph that has a value for every hour. From my understanding Flot uses epoch time for hour values. However wen running the following code the chart doesn't show any values and no error.

```
//Data for 12am and 5pm respectively in epoch time
var data = [[43200000, 20], [61200000, 50]]; 

var dataset = [
 {
  label: "amount",
  data: data,
  color: "#FF0000",
  bars: {
    show: true, 
    align: "center",
    barWidth: 2 * 60 * 60 * 600,
    lineWidth:1
  }
 }
];

var options = {
 yaxis: {}, 
 xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
   //timeformat: "%H",
    tickSize: [1, "hour"], // tick every hour
    min: (new Date(0, 0, 0, 00, 00, 00, 00)).getTime(),
    max: (new Date(0, 0, 0, 24, 00, 00, 00)).getTime()
   }
};

 $.plot($("#flot-placeholder"), dataset, options);
```

[image]

How can I populate values on the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Epoch time starts on 1970-1-1 (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)). Change your min/max values to

```
min: (new Date(1970, 0, 1, 00, 00, 00, 00)).getTime(),
max: (new Date(1970, 0, 1, 24, 00, 00, 00)).getTime()
```

and it works with your data. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmmfes7e/).

But if you only care about hours and not the date, consider using [categories mode](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/index.html), see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06ttww65/).